# Django 1.7 in memory table does not exist for unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have an app that I recently did a migration for that included adding a new table.  I can see that the migration worked, the table is populated, I can access it, etc.  Even when I run

```
python manage.py migrate my_app -l
```

I can see the migration as having been successfully run.

However when I run my unit tests I get:

```
OperationalError: no such table: my_app_my_table
```

The only thing I can thing of is that the in memory database is not running all the migrations?  Or it's not doing it correctly?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case that your migrations aren't actually generating the SQL code you intended, and it's probably worth running [sqlmigrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) on the specific migrations to make sure it's generating code to make the table.

If the SQL code looks right, something weird could have happened and django thinks you ran the migration but it didn't actually change the database.  In that case, you could try restoring an older version of the database and running the migrations on that?